# Expand a div's width untill all the children fit

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple slider so I'm using a div (#container) to hold the items that I need to slide (this div will have overflow:hidden), a div (#slider) that I want to move so that all the items will be moved together, and divs that fit in the slider.

I want the slider's width to expand until all the items fit to the same row with float:left.

I have this jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rBFPL/5/ and I would need some help to make the red divs on the same row and the cyan div expand its width.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/HCYPD/3/

```
#container {
    width : 400px;
    height : 200px;
    position : relative;
    background : yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
    margin : 5px;
    position : absolute;
    background : cyan;
    width: auto;
    height : 190px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#slider div {
    margin : 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position : relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background : red;
}
```

Comment: That's almost what I need, But isn't there a way to do it using only css?

Comment: I'll have to add dynamically loaded items there, and their width will not be the same..

Comment: Posted an update. Haven't tested across browsers, but I believe it should work.

Comment: Updated again. Does this work for you? Tested on Firefox fine here.

Answer (score 0):

I've made this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYm2f/) , I think it does what you say, I've only tested on chrome.

**Update**: Second [**attempt**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYm2f/1/)

```
#container {
    background : yellow;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position : fixed;
    width : 400px;
}
#slider {
    background : cyan;
    position : fixed;
}
#slider div {
    margin : 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    position : relative;
    float : left;
    background : red;
}
```

Comment: No... I need the yellow div to stay with fixed width and the cyan one to be wider than the yellow one